# VirtualBox doesn't display menu bar after login

Tags: 12.04

When I boot Ubuntu 12.04 in VirtualBox, I see VirtualBox's menu bar at the bottom of the screen.  After I log in, the menu bar disappears.  Why?  I really want it back.

Comment: Please include a screenshot. Are you running in seamless mode?

Comment: I think there are preferences for how to show, and whether to show the menu.  Perhaps you can check the settings.  You can access the menu by pressing the host key (right ctrl by default) plus home.  Or try host + F to toggle full-screen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it appears to be a bug in VirtualBox; it only occurs when you're using Unity hardware accelerated. If on the login screen you choose "Ubuntu 2D", the menu will be visible again.

The menu appears to be drawn under the 3D accelerated window - if you have multimonitor on a Windows host, you'll see that the Windows Taskbar also doesn't show if you change focus to another window while leaving VirtualBox in fullscreen mode on the main monitor.

I'm not sure if the bug is in VirtualBox or the host's display drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Is it in [scale mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/59105/11929)?

<kbd>Host</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is the toggle for scale mode (where <kbd>Host</kbd> is <kbd>Right Control</kbd> by default)

Answer (score 0):

You might have accepted to not get notified again about scaled view before installing guest addition which will allow you later to change window size whilst OS append scale to it.

Reset the machine or press `HOST` or `STRG` (right side) + `C`

Good luck!