# What is Unity Panel?

Tags: unity, panel

Could someone point out to me what Unity Panel looks like? I am using version 12.10, 64 bit, US English.

Comment: The top bar is called a -Panel-. The Launcher is the "Dock" at the left. [Unity Official site](http://unity.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: No, the top bar is called the "menu bar". http://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements/19166#19166. Technically, the Launcher *is* the panel, but 'panel' is Gnome terminology and open to misinterpretation. We shouldn't be using it.

Comment: @fabricator4  The entire thing, not counting the AppMenu and the Indicators is called a Panel (I rightfully think is wrongly called Menubar because not only does it hold the menus, but also has the indicator area). It isn't just a Gnome term, in KDE is called a Panel too (in XFCE, LXDE, E17 it's also a Panel and in any case Unity runs on Gnome software so Gnome terms apply). And The Launcher in Unity is the left side "dock", "sidebar", "thing on the left".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official [site](http://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/unity/), there are two «panels»: one on the left hand-side (blue on the image *infra*), called «task panel» (or launcher) and one at the top of the screen (green), called «menu panel».

[image]

Comment: Then the official site should be fixed. The top bar is the menu bar or panel, and the left bar is simply the Launcher.

Answer (score 0):

The entire bar on the left side of the screen is the Unity Panel.[image]

Comment: @ kelvinafox: Thanks for the illustration. As the saying goes, "A picture is worth a thousand words". So what do Ubuntu developers prefer to call it? "Launcher" or "Unity Panel"?

Comment: The whole bar is the Unity Panel and when you click the Ubuntu logo button at the top, the part that opens is called the Launcher.

Comment: @ kelvinafox: Thanks very much. You guys rock! I wish to take this opportunity to wish one and all Merry Christmas.

Comment: Everybody here's glad to help. Have a good Christmas too.

Comment: Umm, when you click the Unity logo on the launcher, what opens is the 'dash'

Comment: Nobody calls that the panel, that's the launcher.